# Is there a way to automatically specify the range of a ComboBox without having to manually change it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that is dynamic, so the length of the column can vary.

[image]

In this case, if I specify the `ListFillRange` to be `A:A`, it will add a lot of empty cells to the ComboBox. I want it to only add the cells that are not empty, so in this case A1, A2, and A3. If however, the length of the column changes to `A1:A4`, I want the ComboBox to automatically add that fourth cell, without manually having to change the Fill Range.

Comment: look into defining the last row of the column then you can loop through each cell in that column and add it to the ComboBox.  Or you can place the items in Column A as a table then refer to that `ListObject`.  It all depends on how often that data in Column A is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to change the `ListFillRange` whenever a cell in column A is changed. Assuming the sheet is `Sheet1` and your ComboBox name is `ComboBox1`, you can do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sheet1
        If Intersect(Target, .Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "A1:A" & lastRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this will keep any empty cells between the first row and `lastRow`. If that's not the behavior you want, then you can replace the line:

```
.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "A1:A" & lastRow
```

..with:

```
'.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = ""    ' You can do this manually.
.ComboBox1.Clear
Dim i As Long, cell As Range
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set cell = .Cells(i, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then .ComboBox1.AddItem (cell.Value)
Next
```

Comment: This might be a silly question, but could you clarify where you run this code? I already have a macro in my Workbook and it doesn't allow me to put two Private Sub methods in the same place.

Comment: It seems like if I remove the "Option Explicit" then it is able to run it. Can you specify if it's the sheet that the Combo Box is located in or if it's the sheet where my column is in that I need to write in the code?

Comment: I'm assuming both the ComboBox and the column are on the same sheet. If so, you put the code under _that_ sheet, which is `Sheet1` in this case (see a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/7iVt4We.png)). If they're not on the same sheet, then you put the code under the sheet that has the column **AND** you'll need to modify the code above to use the other sheet name when using `.ComboBox1`. Hope that's clear.

Comment: If `Option Explicit` is causing problems for you, then you probably have undefined variables. Either define them (using `Dim`) or remove `Option Explicit` which I wouldn't recommend.